# Display search results on the same page in a table with PHP

Tags: php, html, search

I am using a form to search in a database and I would like to know how to display the search results in a table, on the same page (the page can refresh, I don't mind).

My form looks like this:

```
<form id="searchform"  method="post" action = 'search4.php' target = '_blank'>
  <input id="name" style="height: 25px; width: 140px; position: fixed; top: 150px; left: 50px" name="name" type="text" >
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn" style="color: white; font-style: normal; background-color: blueviolet; position: fixed; top: 148px; left: 220px">
</form>
```

search4.php is the script that does the searching in the database and looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username   = 'root';
$password   = '';
$dbname     = 'official_db';

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, null, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}  

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $Name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
} else {
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
}

session_start();
$results = "SELECT * FROM b2b_interfaces WHERE Name LIKE CONCAT ('%', $name, '%')";

$resultSet = $mysqli->query($results);
$numRows = $resultSet->num_rows;
if ($numRows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_object()) {
        echo "{$row->name} {$row->address} {$row->county}  <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No Results";
}
?>
```

In the main script I also have defined a table, but I do not know how to have access to the results from search4.php. I would try something like this:

```
<tbody>
      <?php
      if ($numRows > 0) {
          while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_object()) {
      ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo "{$row->name} " ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row->address} " ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row->county} " ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php
          }
      }
      ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It looks correct, what is the issue?

Comment: *"Display search results on the same page"* - well, get rid of this first `target = '_blank'` while using a conditional statement. and `action = 'search4.php'` => `action = ''`

Comment: You just need to drop your table code (the last block you supplied) where you currently have `echo "{$row->name} {$row->address} {$row->county}  <br>";` in your second block. You'll have to do some adjustments to get all the tags to appear, but I don't see anything wrong w/ what you're doing in general. I could be missing something.

Comment: @Fred -ii- : If I  make `action='`', then how will my script be called? I was thinking just to put all the content of search4.php in the form, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: put your entire code on the same page. If not, then you will need to use ajax

Comment: please check this code http://pastebin.com/yj4vgapS

Answer (score 0):

You can place the search script on the same page, so target the search form to the current page, and place the script on top of the page.

Comment: I have did as you said and the search works, it displays the results nicely in the table on the right of the page, it's just that the first time the page is displayed, I receive an error:`( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line` and in the table, all the database rows are displayed. You can see my code here:http://pastebin.com/qiKAG5Xa

Comment: Great! Ahh that's because it's looking for the posted value of name, but you haven't posted that yet, on top of your php code you should add: if($_POST['name']) { your code } else { } (please upvote my comment if that solved your problem, and mark as solution please)

Comment: OK, so I added if($_POST['name']) {all code here up until </div>..where the table description is finished } else {I put form definition again}. I must be doing something wrong because I still see that error.

Comment: still the same error with your code..no problem, I have found a workaround. Thanks though!